# wpf tooltips -set duration across application

Tags: wpf, tooltip

I can set properties on single control tooltip like duration. But what i need is to set longer duration for ALL tooltips in entire application - all windows, all user controls etc. Is there any clean way to achieve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override the meta-data for the `ToolTipService.ShowDurationProperty` like so:

```
public partial class App : System.Windows.Application {

    static App() {
        ToolTipService.ShowDurationProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(UIElement),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1000));
    }

}
```

The above will make the ToolTip duration 1 second for all UIElements.

Comment: Can we override the meta-data for the ToolTip.MaxWidthProperty like as: ToolTip.MaxWidthProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(UIElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(400)); I took an exception: Default value type does not match type of property 'MaxWidth'.

Comment: @iremce - Try `ToolTip.MaxWidthProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(UIElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(400.0));`