# wpf tooltips add additional string across application

Tags: wpf, tooltip

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080342/wpf-tooltips-set-duration-across-application) but more complicated.

I need to override all tooltips (and all controls that can have one but not have it now) with additional information about this control. I wanted to put something like

```
sender.ToolTip =+ "\n\r" + sender.Name + "(" + sender.Tag + ")";
```

but googled a bit about that with no success.

---

UPDATE

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(FrameworkElement), FrameworkElement.ToolTipOpeningEvent, new RoutedEventHandler((s, e2) =>
        {
            var fe = s as FrameworkElement;
            fe.ToolTip = fe.ToolTip + "\n\r(" + fe.Name + ")";
            //fe.Name + " " + fe.Tag;
        }));

        new MainWindow();
    }
```

nearly works, but:

- for components without tooltip defined, there is no tooltip visible
- for components with tooltip defined it adds value on each show tooltip event
- I had to rename (s, e) to (s, e2) as e is already defined

---

updated with eliminated null exception and protected from duplicate entries

```
            EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(FrameworkElement), FrameworkElement.ToolTipOpeningEvent, new RoutedEventHandler((s, e2) =>
        {
            var fe = (FrameworkElement)s;

            //skip already updated tooltips
            if (fe.ToolTip.ToString().Contains(fe.Name)) return;

            //update tooltip value
            fe.ToolTip = (fe.ToolTip + Environment.NewLine + "(" + ( fe.Tag != null 
                ? string.Join(": ", fe.Name, fe.Tag) 
                : fe.Name
            ) +  ")").Trim();
        }));
```

Still no idea how to override components without tooltip - maybe I could assing "" tooltip to all buttons and other types of controls and than update those which are configured?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Czesc!

You can use Routed Events infrastructure available in WPF to do this.

Call [EventManager.RegisterClassHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597875.aspx) method like this:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(FrameworkElement), FrameworkElement.ToolTipOpeningEvent, new RoutedEventHandler((s, e) =>
            {
                var fe = s as FrameworkElement;
                fe.ToolTip = fe.Name + " " + fe.Tag;                
            }));
```

You can add this code to App.xaml.cs under the constructor:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) 
{ 
    base.OnStartup(e); 
    <code goes here> 
}
```

Comment: hej, And how can I apply this to all tooltips? where to place this code?

Comment: when your applications starts, you an add this to App.xaml.cs:

protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);  <code goes here>      }

Comment: Sorry but still problems, see question